# Why does @PropertyName fail to automatically serialize maps, while it successfully serializes other types?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

ScreenModel.java

```
public class ScreenModel {

    @PropertyName("TEST_FIELD")
    private HashMap<String, Object> testFieldHashMap;

    public HashMap<String, Object> getTestFieldHashMap() {
        return testFieldHashMap;
    }

}
```

addSnapshotListener

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("SCREENS").document(sharedPreferences.getString("documentId", null)).addSnapshotListener((value, error) - > {
if (error != null) return;
    
if (value != null && value.exists()) {
    ScreenModel screenModel = value.toObject(ScreenModel.class);
    if (screenModel.getTestFieldHashMap() == null)
        Log.w("ABC", "111"); // It always print this, why always null?
}});
```

[image]

Why does `@PropertyName` fail to automatically serialize maps, while it successfully serializes other types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't about the type of the field, but about the access modifier. You set the field to be private. To solve this, it's necessary to set the field `public`:

```
@PropertyName("TEST_FIELD")
public HashMap<String, Object> testFieldHashMap;
//
```

Now, the annotation will take into account both the field name as well as the getter when serializing.

Comment: In GSON, why does using `@SerializedName("TEST_FIELD")` allow for serialization of a field even if the access modifier is set to private, but using `@PropertyName("TEST_FIELD")` does not? What is the purpose of this difference?

Comment: I added the `@PropertyName` annotation with the value "TEST_FIELD" before the method this morning and it worked, but I am not sure how or why it worked. Can you explain to me what occurred and the mechanics behind it? [I have attached an image of the ScreenModel class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pURsE.png)

Comment: When you add the `SerializedName` in front of a field it means that you allow that field to be serialized and deserialized. It doesn't matter if it's private or not. Serialization doesn't take into consideration access modifiers. On the other hand, you cannot set `PropertyName` on a field that cannot be seen outside the class.